# Virtual display management on 4k tv

Tags: multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

I'm using 3 monitors, (2) normal and (1) 4k tv that was split into 4 units by the video manager before I switched to 19.04.  I just installed 19.04 and everything is working fine but I can't find a way to get the video output to split the TV up, to give me four more virtual monitors.  It is a small problem and can be worked around but the splitting makes it easier to move around what I want to see.  The hardware is an Intel Haswell APU and its HD 4600 graphics with VGA, HDMI, and DVI outputs.

I tried the gnome multi monitor extension.  I could find no controls that would allow splitting the 4K TV into 4 virtual monitors, unless I missed something.  I switched back to the Plasma desktop as it is easier for an old guy that started with windows back around 3.1.  Thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: I'm not sure of the point of your post since you are just repeating what I said was the hardware.  But since nobody else has responded, maybe you are waiting for a reply.  If so, please clarify what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes, it is an onboard card, I mentioned it to denote the 3 outputs and that they were all being used.  I don't think the solution will have anything to do with the hardware, but that's an assumption and you know what they say about those.  Windows will break the tv into 4 different monitors (total of 6 with other 2 regular monitors) but does it kind of poorly.  I purchased a virtual display manager but it didn't really do anything that windows didn't do.  I'm now faced with buying a new laptop with Win 10, ain't gonna happen, so I'm prepping for the migration to Linux.

Comment: Were you using https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/ ? Please click [edit] to answer; Comments pile up and sooner or later, get pushed off screen, so [edit] is preferred to add facts to a question.